# windows overwrites cups drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, cups, printing

I'm currently trying to enforce grayscale printing at the company I work at.
I have added the printer (sharp mx2600n) to the cups server using the ppd file.
on the web interface i set the color mode to black & white and i have disabled the color module in the ppd file.

now,

When I add the printer in windows clients (http://<>:631/printers/bwprinter) using generic PS driver all is well, but when I use this driver I have no say in windows wether I want it to print duplex or not.
so when I add the printer using the PS drivers added from the site windows compeletely ignores the drivers installed on the server and still prints in full color.

Does anyone have any idea how I can force the cups server to enforce its settings or how to add duplex printing to the generic PS drivers in windows?

thanks in advance